# Assigning retrieved JSON data to a TypeScript object using Angular in a MEAN stack project

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, api, mean-stack

I am working on the Clinic Manager project using the MEAN stack. I have already dealt with the backend, and now I want to display data using Angular. However, I am facing a problem with retrieving data and assigning it to a TypeScript object. I have been trying to solve this problem for a couple of hours, and ChatGPT hasn't been helpful at all. I'm stuck.

I am receiving data from the server in JSON format, and it looks like this:

```
{
    "status": "success",
    "data": {
        "count": 9,
        "patients": [
            {
                "_id": "64787ffc3daccbe20796ec17",
                "name": "Paweł",
                "surname": "Kowalczyk",
                "dateOfBirth": "1990-09-09T22:00:00.000Z",
                "city": "Warszawa",
                "pesel": "10207935608",
                "address": "Marszałkowska 155"
            },
            {
                "_id": "64787ffc3daccbe20796ec1a",
                "name": "Alicja",
                "surname": "Krawczyk",
                "dateOfBirth": "1988-09-15T00:00:00.000Z",
                "city": "Poznań",
                "pesel": "70810738509",
                "address": "Krakowska 45"
            },
```

**data.service.ts**

```
export class DataService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getData(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get<any>('http://localhost:7000/api/v1/patients')
  }

}
```

**patient.model.ts**

```
export class Patient {
    id: string
    name: string
    surname: string
    pesel: string
    dateOfBirth: Date
    city: string
    address: string

    constructor(
        _id: string,
        name: string,
        surname: string,
        dateOfBirth: Date,
        pesel: string,
        city: string,
        address: string) {
        this.id = _id
        this.name = name
        this.surname = surname
        this.pesel = pesel
        this.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth
        this.city = city
        this.address = address
    }
    // getName() {
    //     return this.name
    // }
}
```

And here is my problem, I don't know how to cast my response to patient.model. I assume that creating object by hand is not the answer.

**patients.component.ts**

```
export class PatientsComponent implements OnInit {

  patients: Patient[] = []
  isLoading = true

  constructor(private dataService: DataService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.dataService.getData().subscribe((data) => {
      this.patients = data.data.patients.map((patientData: any) => new Patient(patientData))
    })
  }

}
```

I've tried something like these:

**patients.component.ts**

```
export class PatientsComponent implements OnInit {

  patients: Patient[] = []
  isLoading = true

  constructor(private dataService: DataService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.dataService.getData().subscribe((data) => {
      this.patients = data.data.patients as Patient[]
    })
  }

}
```

and

```
this.dataService.getData().subscribe((data) => {
      this.patients = <Patient[]>data.data.patients
    })
```

or

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.dataService.getData().subscribe((data) => {
      this.patients = data.data.patients.map((patientData: any) => new Patient(patientData))
    })
  }
```

But it gives me an error or it simply doesn't work (I don't get an array of Patient, just an array of objects). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your 2nd and 3rd attempts work in this [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-mi7cep?file=src%2Fmain.ts). Can you reproduce your error in StackBlitz?